# Making a card game using nestef if | Python

Tags: python

So, I have a homework. As you see below there're some cards below and each has a name. they're numbered from 0 to 35 and from left top to bottom. User enters a number and program has to tell the name, color and the number of the card. But there're some rules for it.

1. I can only use nested if and operators. Can't use while or other functions.
2. I can use max 13 if
3. can't use 36 if, else swap
   [this is the image of cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvvlP.png)

I am not sure about what to do after this...

'''

```
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    
if num == 0 or num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 3:
    print("6")
if num == 4 or num == 5 or num == 6 or num == 7:
    print('7')
if num == 8 or num == 9 or num == 10 or num == 11:
    print('8')
if num == 12 or num == 13 or num == 14 or num == 15:
    print('9')
if num == 16 or num == 17 or num == 18 or num == 19:
    print('10')
if num == 20 or num == 21 or num == 22 or num == 23:
    print('vale')
if num == 24 or num == 25 or num == 26 or num == 27:
    print('queen')
if num == 28 or num == 29 or num == 30 or num == 31:
    print('king')
if num == 32 or num == 33 or num == 34 or num == 35:
    print('tus')
```

'''

Comment: That's not how this service works, sorry. You post your attempt, people tell you what's wrong with it / help to improve it. Not you post your homework, people solve it for you.

Comment: Hint: The cards are arranged in 4 rows and 9 columns. 4 + 9 = 13, which is the maximum number of if statements you're allowed. Can you use the row and column to determine the suit and value of a card? Can you compute the row and column from a single number from 0 -  35?

Comment: @Gameplay first of all I've seen dozens of people do it. Second of all if I don't find any answer teacher will answer it anyways so technically I won't be finding the answer myself. About posting my attempt I'll be posting it as soon as I'll finish my research about this task.

Comment: @BilltheLizard yes teacher said "as you see there're 4 rows so" but he didn't finish the sentence. and answers of both your questions are yes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You urgently need to learn about how to test if an entry exists in an array. This `if` is absolutely out of control. Even better, **USE MATH** and determine which type of square it is. This is a simple modulo operation.

Comment: @tadman I literally started 2 weeks ago... :')

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning. Just pointing out you can't keep brute-forcing it like this. Let the code do the work for you, don't work to get code. Always look for patterns and ways of simplifying your code, as in the process of doing that you'll often find lots of little mistakes.

Comment: @tadman I did a small research about "how to test if an entry exists in an array" and I found different ways. most of them are loops, set(), count() and etc. The thing is none of those matched the description. I didn't understand the square part tho.

Comment: @tadman I totally agree with you and the user named Gameplay. It's just I have a bunch of incomplete ideas like this code and the one I mentioned up there. It's a lot complicated when you see a task like this for the first time when the hardest task you have done last time is to find the next date of the date that was chosen by the user.

Comment: A) I think you're misunderstanding the cards. They're "clubs" (C), "hearts" (H), "spades" (S) and "diamonds" (D). B) Their "suit" is based on a modulo operation as there are 13 cards per suit, 4 suits, so you can easily work out which is which in a 0..51 index.

Comment: So spend a moment to learn about [modulo math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and how it can convert a number in the range of 0..51 into 0..3. Then learn how you can use that 0..3 value to index an array like `[ "Diamonds", "Spades" "Hearts", "Clubs" ]`.

Comment: @tadman oh about the card names, yes I know I don't know their names because English is my third language. and about the math part, I'm on it, sir.

Comment: Just helping to clarify so it'll make more sense for us. The description you've used required a bit of decoding, but I get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for in one line:

```
print(([str(i) for i in range(6, 11)] + ['vale', 'queen', 'king', 'tus'])[(int(input('Enter a number: '))) // 4])
```

The goal is to create a list of avalaible cards. Then use euclidien division by 4 to select the right card...

Comment: thanks for helping even thought I can't use your code because apperantly they don't match teachers description. I will try to understand it's logic and try to convert it something that description is looking for. thank you again

Comment: What do you mean by range(6, 11)

Comment: range(6, 11) create a yield [6,7,8,9,10]